# ctx.clearRect canvas sprite

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, drawimage, requestanimationframe

I am wondering how I could alter my Javascript to only clear the falling sprites, and not the entire canvas (as it does currently).

I hope to place multiple other (animated) sprites on the canvas, which do not appear with the way my `function animate` is structured.

Is there a way so that if there was another image/sprite was on the canvas, it would not be affected by the `function animate.`

I'm thinking that this line needs to change:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Though I have no idea what parameters I would need to place inside.
The falling sprites draw at a size of `60x60`, but as they fall downwards this is where I am a bit stuck with clearing the only the sprite path.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1408;
canvas.height = 640; 
canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvasHeight = canvas.height;

var orangeEnemy = new Image();
orangeEnemy.src = "http://www.catholicsun.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cropped-sun-favicon-512x512-270x270.png";
var yellowEnemy = new Image();
yellowEnemy.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/o/S/R/S/h/9/transparent-red-circle-hi.png";

var srcX;
var srcY;
var enemySpeed = 2.75;
var images = [orangeEnemy, yellowEnemy];
var spawnLineY=-50;
var spawnRate=2500;
var spawnRateOfDescent=1.50;
var lastSpawn=-1;
var objects=[];
var startTime=Date.now();
animate();


    function spawnRandomObject() {
        var object = {
                x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 15),
                y: spawnLineY,
                image: images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
            }
        objects.push(object);
    }

    function animate(){
        var time=Date.now();
        if(time>(lastSpawn+spawnRate)){
            lastSpawn=time;
            spawnRandomObject();
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


        // move each object down the canvas
        for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
            var object=objects[i];
            object.y += enemySpeed;
            ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x, object.y, 60, 60);

        }

    }
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:3px solid"></canvas>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest way would be to overlay another canvas, specifically for your sprites, atop your current canvas (requires a bit of CSS). Put all your sprites in one, everything else in the other. The clearRect() in your animate() function will then only apply to your sprite canvas, and not the other.

Otherwise, you will have to keep track of the positions of the sprites, and clear each programatically with 60x60 rectangles using clearRect(offsetX, offsetY, 60, 60).

P.S. excuse the non-formatted answer... still figuring SO out

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. I had considered a second canvas but wasn't entirely sure how it would work with the context of a canvas game I have to make. I followed how to draw a 2nd canvas on Stack which showed sample CSS (alignments etc.) and my test canvas works well. I even managed to get collision to work, which I wasn't sure would with two canvases (you can tell I don't know a lot of JS!) Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Clear once for performance.

You are much better off clearing the whole canvas and redrawing the sprites. Using the previous position, checking for overlap and then clearing each sprite in turn, making sure you don't clear an existing sprite will take many more CPU cycles than clearing the screen once.

The clear screen function is very fast and is done in hardware, the following is the results of a performance test on Firefox (currently the quickest renderer) of clearing 65K pixels using just one call for whole area then 4 calls each a quarter, then 16 calls each clearing a 16th. (µs is 1/1,000,000th second)

```
Each test clears 256*256 pixels Each sample is 100 tests
'Clear 1/1' Mean time: 213µs ±4µs 1396 samples
'Clear 4/4' Mean time: 1235µs ±14µs 1390 samples     
'Clear 16/16' Mean time: 4507µs ±42µs 1405 samples
```

As you can see clearing 65K pixels is best done in one call with the actual javascript call adding about 100µs to do.

On Firefox the number of pixels to clear does not affect the execution time of the call to `clearRect` with a call `clearRect(0,0,256,256)` and `clearRect(0,0,16,16)` both taking ~2µs

Apart from the speed, trying to clear overlapping animated sprites per sprite becomes extremely complicated and can result in 100s of clear calls with only a dozen sprites. This is due to the overlapping.

Comment: Some interesting calculations there; thanks for explaining them. You confirm how difficult it would be to clearrect and redraw moving elements! I followed through with just creating a second canvas so that I could animate a separate sprite.